# Matlab histogram converted to Latex makes blurry image

Tags: matlab, histogram

I´am trying to import a matlab histogram to latex. So I generated the plot and saved it with  
`print -depsc MyPicture`.
Afterwards I loaded the .eps File with

```
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth, center]{pictures/MyPicture.eps}
```

The resulting image has a really low quality.

[image]

The above mentioned method works fine with normal graph plots.

Edit: I found a workaround using the [matlab2tikz script](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz), which generates a tex-File.

Solution: I used `-dpdf` to save the plot and used [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12987-how-to-save-a-matlab-graphic-in-a-right-size-pdf) matlab code to cut the white spaces.

Comment: Something somewhere is converting to .jpg.  The jpg may be embedded in a pdf.  What are you comping with (`latex`, `pdflatex` etc?).  If you're compiling directly to pdf, how are you converting the .eps?

Comment: Can you view your eps directly and check if it is blurry? Matlab prints bitmaps for certain colour surfaces, even if you ask for vector graphics.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something somewhere is converting to .jpg.  I can tell from some of the pixels and from seeing quite a few jpgs in my time.  The jpg may be embedded in a pdf.  If you're compiling to pdf, at some point there's a conversion step that not only converts vector to raster graphics, but over-compresses them.  My matlab (R2019a) seems to generate raster histograms in .eps files, but not to compress them this badly, though they're not pretty.  `-dpdf` gives me vector graphics and `-dpng` gives me clean rasters without the jpg artefacts.

I happened to have a matlab window open, and your `print` statement produces a nice sharp (vector) image.  `print -dpdf figure1` does too, but that would need cropping `-dsvg` gives a nice vector graphic with very similar borders to the .eps.  That can then be imported into pdflatex using the `svg` package or converted using inkscape.

When compiling directly to pdf, you're probably using [epstopdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) or ps2pdf behind the scenes; this in turn uses ghostscript.  Some of the [ghostscript options](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#EPS_parameters) affect the compression  of the output, and these can be configured by using epstopdf explicitly.

Comment: I am not a latex expert. I used PDFLaTeX to compile it. Whats confusing to me, is the fact that the graph plots are vector images and the histos not..